# Invalid check digit: 4 Tecnick Barcode php

Tags: php, barcode

Am trying to generate a `UPC` barcode using `\Com\Tecnick\Barcode` php, when I verify this code online is valid `6154000008055` plus I got it from an existing product.

But when I pass it to my code it trigger error `Invalid check digit: 4`

```
$barcode = new \Com\Tecnick\Barcode\Barcode();
$barcodeData = base64_encode($barcode->getBarcodeObj(
    'UPCA', //EAN13
    6154000008055, 
    -3, 
    -30, 
    'black', 
    array(0, 0, 0, 0)
)->setBackgroundColor('white')->getPngData());
```

Please any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: Pass a string instead?

Comment: Passing it as a string didn't work also